# HTTP-Post with Requests fails: BadStatusLine

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I got a problem with the following code. While trying to upload a file to the API using a POST-Request I get an error saying

```
File "upload.py", line 44, in <module>
    so.uploadData("./test.txt")
  File "upload.py", line 37, in uploadData
    req = requests.post("http://"+server, data=payload, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 412, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

My Code looks like this:

```py
filedata= open(path, 'r')
payload = {'name': self.username, 'file':filedata}
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': "multipart/form-data"}
req = requests.post("http://"+server, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not building a valid multipart/form-data POST request - it is building a application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Overriding the `Content-type` header does not change the way that the data is posted. The server sees an invalid request and drops the connection, which causes the error that you see in your client.

The easiest way to POST multipart/form-data with `requests` is to use the `files` parameter:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as filedata:
    payload = {'name': self.username}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36'}
    req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, files={'file': filedata})
```

This way `requests` will construct a valid multipart/form-data POST request.

The other way to do it, if you did not specifically require that the request use multipart/form-data is not to override the `Content-type` header:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as filedata:
    payload = {'name': self.username, 'file': filedata}
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36'}
    req = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I even tried this before but due other bugs it didn't work.